# Gitlab - Jira integration: transitions to "Done" do not work

Tags: gitlab, jira, integration

I would like to understand why the following Gitlab <-> Jira integration does not work. What I mean by "not working" is that tickets in "In Progress" or "In Review" state do no transition to "Done" when Gitlab Merge request referencing them (using Closes JIRA-TICKET-ID) is merged.

The Gitlab integration is setup so that "Transition Jira issues to their final state: Move to Done" see figure below: [image: Gitlab setup]

The tickets are bound to this specific workflow:

[image: Jira Workflow]

Looking through `https://yourcompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/ISSUE-123/transitions` on the specific ticket for which the transition did not automatically happen after corresponding merge request had been merged shows:

```
{
  "expand": "transitions",
  "transitions": [
    ...
    {
      "id": "141",
      "name": "Resolve",
      "to": {
        "name": "Done",
        "statusCategory": {
          "name": "Done"
        }
      },
      ...
    },
    {
      "id": "171",
      "name": "Close",
      "to": {
        "name": "Closed",
        "statusCategory": {
          "name": "Done"
        }
      },
      ...
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

I really do not understand why the transition did not happen - "Resolve" (id: 141) transition is to "Done" (green, statusCategory "Done")... according to all documentation available and what is written specifically in Gitlab, it should have happened.

Did anyone have experience with similar, ideally same situation, and was able to solve it?

Comment: What are the conditions/validators for the "Resolve" transition? And does the user in integration has correct permissions such as "Transition Issues"?

Comment: @stuck There are 0 conditions and 0 validators on the transition and the permissions ("Transition Issues" specifically) are set correctly.

Comment: Hmm, is there a screen on transition?

Comment: I am learning new staff :)... looked for it in the transition definition and there is "Screen: None - it will happen instantly". So, no :(.

Comment: Ok, what about the logs? Can you share the logs inside Jira and/or Gitlab after performing that operation?